# Getting Components By Schema Name

Tags: 2013, dd4t

I am trying to get the List of Components using the Schema ID. I am doing following steps.

```
var queryParameters = new ExtendedQueryParameters();
queryParameters.PublicationId = publicationID;
queryParameters.QuerySchemas = new[] { schemaID.ToString() };
ComponentFactory.FindComponents(queryparameters);
```

Here, SchemaID is the short ID of Schema.

1. Do I need to put whole TCMURI or am I correct in this?
2. How to sort list by Last Published Date?

Comment: I got the answer for my 1st question. We need to put whole TCM URI of the Schema. Please help for the second question. How can I sort it by last published date?

Answer (score 5):

You are using the DD4T stack. Which is fine, although I would recommend to use the standard CD API, as Mihai mentions.

To sort the list by Last Publish Date you should be able to do this (Untested):

```
var queryParameters = new ExtendedQueryParameters();
queryParameters.PublicationId = publicationID;
queryParameters.QuerySchemas = new[] { schemaID.ToString() };
queryParameters.QuerySortField = "ItemLastPublishedDate";
queryParameters.SortType = ExtendedQueryParameters.MetaSortFieldType.DATETIME;
queryParameters.QuerySortOrder = ExtendedQueryParameters.MetaQueryOrder.Descending
ComponentFactory.FindComponents(queryparameters);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are quoting some custom code. What is `ExtendedQueryParameters` and `ComponentFactory`? They are not Tridion CD API.

For a standard CD API query, you would use the `Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query` namespace. This allows you to specify Criterias and filter/modifiers such as number of results and sorting direction.

A pseudo-code example is the following:

```
Criteria criteria = new ItemSchemaCriteria(123);
Query query = new Query(criteria);
SortParameter sorting = new SortParameter(SortParameter.ItemLastPublishColumn, SortParameter.Ascending);
query.AddSorting(sorting);
string[] ids = query.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: ExtendedQueryParameters is DD4T. :)

Comment: It did seem familiar :)